# Can Localhost resolve to multiple IP addresses?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, ip

I have a asp.net web site using wcf services for database interaction. Web site config refers to WCF services by using localhost. When I deployed both web site and wcf services, wcf services can't be accessed by using server name. It requires me to type explicit IP address. Is it possible that localhost can resolve to multiple IP addresses?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the relevance to the rest of your question, but

> Is it possible that localhost can resolve to multiple IP addresses?

[Yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost). `127.0.0.1` and `::1`, for example.

Perhaps you mean to ask a different question? How is this related to *"wcf services can't be accessed by using server name"*? The server isn't called `localhost`, seen from another machine's perspective.

Comment: My theory is that since web site refers to wcf services by using localhost, if localhost resolves into multiple IP addresses, web site refers to wrong IP.

Comment: Perhaps you should just post the exact error message, not make up theories.

Comment: My question is clear. If you have something to say, say; otherwise thanks for your effort.

Comment: If your question was clear, I'm sure I would be able to answer it, having enough knowledge on the subject. If you don't want to provide relevant information: good luck getting a helpful answer.

Comment: I don't have access to the server, I can't get any error message.

Comment: That troubles things a bit, but to recap: if your website's web.config contains a `<client><endpoint address="http://127.0.0.1/FooService.svc" /></client>` section it works, but with `<client><endpoint address="http://localhost/FooService.svc" /></client>` it doesn't?

Comment: Well then yes, IIS can be configured to only listen to `127.0.0.1` and `localhost` can resolve to `::1`, making the call fail. But if you can't access the server, or the logs, or the configuration, or the exception messages your WCF client gets, there's nothing to do but guess and just type the IP address in the config.